# Handler queueIdle called twice before last message arrived

Tags: android, multithreading

i am reading EAT book and there are a code samples that show queueIdle utilisation.

Below codes starts 10 thread and every new thread throws 10 messages. And i expect that after every message delivered, looper will be quited.

```
@Override
public boolean queueIdle() {
    if (mIsFirstIdle) {
       mIsFirstIdle = false;
       return true;
    }

    mConsumerHandler.getLooper().quit();
    return false;
}
```

> “ The idle slots can occur before the first message, between messages,
>   and after the last message. ” Excerpt From: Anders Göransson.
>   “Efficient Android Threading.” iBooks.

So I think that,  queueIdle will be called with first message and last message, so it ensures that every message will be delivered.

But i got below error, because queueIdle called unexpectedly ??

> **sending message to a Handler on a dead thread**

is it normal or sample codes is wrong ?

**Code sample**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.MessageQueue;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Random;


public class ConsumeAndQuitThreadActivity extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ConsumeAndQuitThread consumeAndQuitThread = new ConsumeAndQuitThread();
        consumeAndQuitThread.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Log.v("EATDEGUB","thread " + i + " started.");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        Log.v("EATDEGUB","currentThread  "+ Thread.currentThread().getId() +  "  : enqueueData is " + i);
                        SystemClock.sleep(new Random().nextInt(10));
                        consumeAndQuitThread.enqueueData(i);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    private static class ConsumeAndQuitThread extends Thread implements MessageQueue.IdleHandler {

        private static final String THREAD_NAME = "ConsumeAndQuitThread";

        public Handler mConsumerHandler;
        private boolean mIsFirstIdle = true;

        public ConsumeAndQuitThread() {
            super(THREAD_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            mConsumerHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    //mIsFirstIdle=true;
                    Log.v("EATDEGUB","handled message is " + msg.what);
                }
            };

            Looper.myQueue().addIdleHandler(this);
            Looper.loop();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean queueIdle() {
            Log.v("EATDEGUB","Thread " +currentThread().getId());

            if (mIsFirstIdle) {
                mIsFirstIdle = false;
                return true;
            }

            Log.v("EATDEGUB", "Thread " +currentThread().getId() + " is closed by calling quit()");


    mConsumerHandler.getLooper().quit();
        return false;
    }

    public void enqueueData(int i) {
        mConsumerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(i);
    }
}
```

}

**LOG**

```
02-24 13:54:41.490    thread 0 started.
02-24 13:54:41.490    Thread 9590
02-24 13:54:41.490    thread 1 started.
02-24 13:54:41.490    thread 2 started.
02-24 13:54:41.490    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.490    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.490    thread 3 started.
02-24 13:54:41.490    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.490    thread 4 started.
02-24 13:54:41.490    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.490    thread 5 started.
02-24 13:54:41.490    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    thread 6 started.
02-24 13:54:41.495    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    thread 7 started.
02-24 13:54:41.495    thread 8 started.
02-24 13:54:41.495    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    thread 9 started.
02-24 13:54:41.495    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.495    handled message is 0
02-24 13:54:41.495    Thread 9590

**02-24 13:54:41.495    Thread 9590 is closed by calling quit()**

After this time, none of remaining message can be delivered. >>

02-24 13:54:41.500    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.500    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.500    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.505    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.505    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.505    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.505    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.510    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.510    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 1
02-24 13:54:41.510    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.510    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.515    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.515    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.515    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.520    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.520    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.520    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.520    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.525    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.525    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 2
02-24 13:54:41.530    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.530    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.530    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.530    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.530    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.535    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.535    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.535    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.535    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.535    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.535    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.540    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.540    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 3
02-24 13:54:41.540    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.540    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.545    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.545    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.545    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.545    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.550    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.550    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.550    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.555    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 4
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.565    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.570    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.570    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.570    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.575    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.580    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.580    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.580    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.580    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.580    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 5
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9591  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.585    currentThread  9593  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.590    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.590    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.590    currentThread  9598  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.595    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.595    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.600    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.600    currentThread  9596  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.600    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.600    currentThread  9592  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.600    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 6
02-24 13:54:41.600    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 7
02-24 13:54:41.605    currentThread  9600  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.605    currentThread  9594  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.605    currentThread  9595  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.605    currentThread  9599  : enqueueData is 9
02-24 13:54:41.610    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 8
02-24 13:54:41.615    currentThread  9597  : enqueueData is 9
```

Answer (score 0):

one year later ;) I am reading this book and have exactly the same question.

My guess is that the line with *sleep* is introducing idle times

```
SystemClock.sleep(new Random().nextInt(10));
```

The second time an idle time is detected the MessageQueue calls queueIdle that kills the handler and returns false. From now on all calls to sendMessage will be done on an Handler and a Thread that does not exist anymore, hence the error.

That was my guess so I removed the line with *sleep* and launched the app: sometimes it works but most of the time the error remains. So either my guess is wrong, or idle times can occur for different reasons.